# Install PCL Library on Python/Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: python, ubuntu, point-cloud-library

How do you install PCL Library on Python/Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

I've tried different ways to do so, without luck.

Trying to `import pcl` results in:

```
ImportError: libpcl_keypoints.so.1.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install it as a system-wide library, versus a Python module.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sweptlaser/python3-pcl
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pcl
```

from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160219/how-to-make-pcl-library-and-python-pcl-run-on-ubuntu-18-04-2)

Answer (score 2):

I tried much to solve this issue. The drawback is here:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcl-dev -y
```

If you run this, it will install libpcl-dev with a higher version which will be conflicted with that libpcl-dev 1.7 you will install later. Here are some steps to raise the issue:

initially add [Ubuntu 16 source list](https://gist.github.com/rohitrawat/60a04e6ebe4a9ec1203eac3a11d4afc1)
then run below lines one by one.

```
sudo apt-get update

pip install python-pcl

sudo apt-get install libpcl-keypoints1.7

sudo apt-get install libpcl-outofcore1.7

sudo apt-get install libpcl-people1.7

sudo apt-get install libpcl-recognition1.7

sudo apt-get install libpcl-registration1.7

sudo apt-get install libpcl-segmentation1.7

sudo apt-get install libpcl-surface1.7
```

Now, if you get error "***libpng12-0***", do this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/libpng12

sudo apt update

sudo apt-get install libpng12-0

sudo apt-get install libpcl-tracking1.7

sudo apt-get install libflann1.8

sudo apt-get install libpcl-visualization1.7
```

finally,

```
python

>>> import pcl
```

***Congratulation : PCL is successfully imported***

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. Unfortunately, in step  10 (libpcl-survace1.7) I got the error: Depends: libvtk6.2 but it is not going to be installed. Ubuntu 18 has 6.3 V already installed.

Comment: Hi Capdi, have you fixed your problem?